# Overriding android material design alert dialogs

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm attempting to change the color of the "cancel" button on the android L alert dialogs by setting the alertDialogTheme attribute of my theme as follows:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
```

Right now the AlertDialogStyle is empty:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="android:style/Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">

</style>
```

I know I can use the

```
android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle
```

property to update the color/style of those buttons. The issue I'm having is that by descending from the Theme.Material.Light.Dialog style, all of my dialogs are having their width reduced to (what appears to be) wrap_content. I have a few custom alert dialogs, and that width looks atrocious. Has anyone run into this problem and if so has anyone fixed it?

EDIT: I've also tried setting the parent to

```
android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to descend from

```
android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert
```

That fixed everything right up.